# webpack --optimize-minimize vs -p

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, production

I am doing server side rendering inside my react app. Inside of app I have a few pictures so i have loder for them inside webpack-config

```
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/img/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      },
```

If I run my code this way

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --optimize-minimize --config webpack.config.prod.js,
```

I get an error

```
Warning: Prop `src` did not match. Server: "assets/img/profilna.1b1788096b2a10afe508dff672e50072.jpg" Client: "/assets/img/profilna.1b1788096b2a10afe508dff672e50072.jpg"
```

but if I run it like this

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --p --config webpack.config.prod.js,
```

everything is good and functions perfectly like I want.

Why is that?

As I read `-p` is equivalent of

`webpack --optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV="'production'"`

Since I am already setting production enviroment I don't need --define

Answer (score 1):

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production
```

with this, you are setting Node `process.env.NODE_ENV` but is not "being passed" or used - while bundling - inside the app. Basically, you need to create global variables for the app and set `NODE_ENV` to what you need by webpack. And this is what...

`--define process.env.NODE_ENV="'production'"`

...does. It will use [Webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to set global `process.env.NODE_ENV` to be used while bundling the app.

I know this sounds a little bit unclear, I struggled to understand it myself but hopefully, documentation will clear that out.

> Technically, NODE_ENV is a system environment variable that Node.js
>   exposes into running scripts. It is used by convention to determine
>   dev-vs-prod behavior by server tools, build scripts, and client-side
>   libraries. Contrary to expectations, process.env.NODE_ENV is not set
>   to "production" within the build script

See ["Specifying the environment"](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-environment) for an example.

Comment: I am strugeling to understand this. 

For example if I run the code my way with --optimize-minimize
and I put ```console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)``` inside my webpack.config.js I get 'production'

That would say that this part from documentation is not true and the example that they give works for me.

'Contrary to expectations, process.env.NODE_ENV is not set to "production" within the build script webpack.config.js. Thus, conditionals like process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '[name].[hash].bundle.js' : '[name].bundle.js' within webpack configurations do not work as expected.'

Comment: it will not work within the build if you set it with cross-env so you can't reach it inside component for example. The only way to reach it in your code is trough explicitly define it with DefinePlugin.

Comment: but I can reach it, because the next part of my code goes like this where I check for production environment and use .json file depending if NODE_ENV is production or development, and in my case it uses app.prod.json.

```const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const prodConf = isProd ? require('../../../conf/app.prod.json') : {}```

Comment: it's a `-p` that sets production mode which also sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production`. If you would set `process.env.SOMETHING=something` you won't reach it in your code without DefinePlugin

Comment: but in my example I am not using -p, I use --optimize-minimize and cross-env NODE_ENV=production, how was I able to reach it then?

Comment: and within your react app `process.env.NODE_ENV=production` ?

Comment: yes, it part of my server budnle that I also start like this ```cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --optimize-minimize --config webpack.config.server.prod.js```,  and then inside of it the first thing I do is my above example where I check if it's production environment. If it is I run app on different port.

Comment: so you access it in `webpack.config.server.prod.js`. I don't think you will access it within the app though.

Comment: No, I access it within the app, react component

Comment: I apologize. Seems this is not the case. I checked it again. Within the react component it is undefined. But what is the purpose off ```cross-env NODE_ENV=production``` then, what does it do? Also if with -p I set production enviroment, how do I set development environment then. Always thought that ```cross-env NODE_ENV=development``` would do the trick?

Comment: cross-env will set NODE_ENV for scripts like `webpack.config.server.prod.js`. But to have it set in build you need DefinePlugin.

Comment: Thx. I am still not complety clear how this works because in my index.js file which is the entry point in my webpack for server bundle I can access NODE_ENV while inside of app.js which is the entry point for my client bundle I can not. Need to do more testing.